# When is $\gcd(a+b,c)=\gcd(a,c-b)$?

Tags: number-theory

Let $a,b,c$ be three positive integers. Under which conditions do we have $\gcd(a+b,c)=\gcd(a,c-b)$ ?

Comment: It is probably easier to view this as gcd(a+b,c+b)=gcd(a,c), or else gcd(a-c,c+b)=gcd(a,c) (assuming without loss that $a>c$ in the latter case).

Answer (score -1):

Set $d= a+b$. Then the question becomes: When is $\gcd(d,c) = \gcd(d-b,c-b)$?

Let $g=\gcd(d,c)$. Then $d=sg$ and $c=tg$ (with $s,t$ coprime). So there are two cases when the sought-for equality will not hold:

- $g$ does not divide $b$ (equivalently, $b$ is not a multiple of $g$).
- $b=rg$ such that $s-r$ and $t-r$ have a common factor, so the resulting $\gcd$ is a multiple of $g$. This is harder to test for.

Sample case: $(a,b,c) = (40, 6, 16)$. $\gcd(a+b,c) \ne \gcd(a,b) \ne (gcd(a,b-c)$

Comment: @downvoter I would love to know what you find unclear or wrong about this answer so I can improve it.